# Do interactive view controller transitions in iOS 7 require a navigation controller, or can I simply do it modally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, viewcontroller

I'm interested in using interactive view controller transitions to present and dismiss a view controller. I know for a simple, non-interactive, animated transition I don't need to use a navigation controller, but it's less clear for interactive transitions.

It seems you set the view controller's that you are to transition to's `transitionDelegate` to say, `self`, and then implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` delegate with

```
- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController
                          interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationController
```

But is it possible to do without the use of a navigation controller? Just use `presentViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

You set the `transitioningDelegate` of the `UIViewController` and use:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForPresentation:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator
```

and

`- (id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForDismissal:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator`